# Right alignment and more efficient way to code

Tags: python

I am supposed to write a code that results in this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27
0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
0 6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
0 7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
0 8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

and this is my code:

```
  for i in range(10):
    print("0", end="  ")
  print("")

  for i in range(0, 10):
    print(i, end="  ")
  print("")

 for i in range(10):
   i = i * 2
   print(i, end="  ")
 print("")

 for i in range(10):
     i = i * 3
     print(i, end="  ")
 print("")

for i in range(10):
    i = i * 4
    print(i, end="  ")
print("")

for i in range(10):
    i = i * 5
    print(i, end="  ")
print("")

for i in range(10):
    i = i * 6
    print(i, end="  ")
print("")

for i in range(10):
    i = i * 7
    print(i, end="  ")
print("")

for i in range(10):
    i = i * 8
    print(i, end="  ")
print("")

for i in range(10):
    i = i * 9
    print(i, end="  ")
print("")
```

I just coded a bunch a 'for' statement and I feel like there would be a way that I could code where I don't have to be too repetitive. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it? And how do I get the right alignment?

Thank you.

Comment: would you say that your wrote a for loop `for` each `n in range(10)`?

Comment: yeah I did, I wrote a for statement for each line

Comment: that was a hint...

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is run a loop from 0 to 9. This loop variable will be the "multiplier". At each iteration, multiply the multiplier with numbers 0 to 9. As shown below, I've done this with `map` + `int.__mul__`, but there are other (possibly faster ways, if performance is your concern) of doing this.

To justify, you can use `str.format` with right justification (`{:>3}.format(number)`).

```
for i in range(10):
     print(*map('{:>3}'.format, map(i.__mul__, range(10))))

  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
  0   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18
  0   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27
  0   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36
  0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45
  0   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54
  0   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63
  0   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72
  0   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81
```